# NullPointerExceptiom from LogCat

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LogCat entry meaning 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044001/logcat-entry-meaning-2)

LogCat say that the problem is with the Array Adapter that it has a NullPointerException. How can I solve this problem? The application crashes if I press the button add.

```
package com.example.to_doliste;

import java.util.List;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private CommentsDataSource datasource;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        List<Comment> values = datasource.getAllComments();
```

Array Adapter get build

```
        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      }
```

it is used here

```
      public void onClick(View view) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Comment>) getListAdapter();
        Comment comment = null;
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:

          String comments;
            EditText Feld1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            if (Feld1.getText().toString().length() == 0)
                    {
                return;
                    }

            comments = (Feld1.getText().toString());

            Feld1.setText(String.valueOf(comments));


          adapter.add(comment);
          break;
        case R.id.delete:
          if (getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
            comment = (Comment) getListAdapter().getItem(0);
            datasource.deleteComment(comment);
            adapter.remove(comment);
          }
          break;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
```

here the adapter stops

```
      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        datasource.open();
        super.onResume();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        datasource.close();
        super.onPause();
      }

    }
```

Comment: Please add the LogCat (stack trace) output

Comment: 12-26 18:33:09.651: E/AndroidRuntime(26038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 18:33:09.651: E/AndroidRuntime(26038): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 18:33:09.651: E/AndroidRuntime(26038):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)

Comment: You should slow down and try to solve these problems yourself before posting them. This is your third question in a half hour. Also you should accept the best answer to each previous question.

Comment: Wait this is the same question: [LogCat entry meaning 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14044001/1267661). Shall I post the same answer?

Comment: This information should be an edit to your older question, not a new question.

Comment: @Sam : yes i agree with you. difference is that user1929838 include code in this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
Comment comment = null;
```

You are trying to add comment to adapter but  comment is null. You are not updating any new value in comment after initializing it to null, so update it before adding or removing it from adapter.

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen this, thank you